# What is merge equivalent for "when not matched by source then delete" in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are converting legacy code to Snowflake SQL. Our legacy has merge as follows

```
MERGE tb1 AS T 
USING src1 AS S
ON (
   S.id= T.id
   AND S.cd= T.cd
 )
  WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT
(
    id,
    cd,
    bl,
    lb
)
VALUES
(S.ID, S.cd, S.bl, S.lb)
 WHEN MATCHED AND (
                 S.bl<> T.bl
                 OR S.lb<> T.lb
             ) THEN
UPDATE SET T.bl= S.bl,
           T.lb= S.lb
 WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
 DELETE;
```

I'm able to migrate the syntax for not matched insert and matched update, but unable to find equivalent for not matched delete.

Comment: What is the original dialect of this query? Deleting when not matched is a non-standard extension (as are `BY TARGET` and `BY SOURCE`). I guess you could outer join the target table to the source table to identify rows that exist in the target, but not in the source, but that would make the `insert` `when not matched` not possible. I guess you'll need to split this into two statements: one to insert and update records, and one to delete rows that no longer occur in the source.

Comment: This is clearly SQL Server syntax, which isn't supported by Snowflake.  If you are trying to get a target to be the same as a source, it's likely more efficient to just `DELETE` everything and insert the source again.  This avoids the full scan to get comparisons and might actually load faster in most cases.  If you don't want to do that, you should just add a `DELETE` statement after your `MERGE` to remove old records that no longer exist.